# Isolate WebComponent JS libraries

Tags: html, web-component, angular-components, shadow-dom, custom-element

We have main big application and are going to create separate small applications (microservices) using different libraries (Angular, React etc.) and compile them into webcomponent to use them anywhere. The main application has some libraries (example underscore.js), some of our components use the same libraries (example lodash.js), in this scenario we see a lot of conflicts when using webcomponents inside main application. Do you have any ideas on how can we isolate webcomponent libraries and they can work in isolated mode. Also we have used ShadowDOM, but no luck.

Comment: If you are going to create micro services and components that you want to use everywhere then I suggest not using any external libraries for these. This will allow them to be used anywhere. If you use libraries like Angular or React then the components become less portable. Even if you use lodash or other libraries you create less portable code then if you don't use any libraries. Your application can use whatever it wants, but your components should use few to no libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. But base on microservice architecture you can use any frameworks and should be isolated and independent shippable. I am trying to achieve this approach on frontend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There's no such *isolated mode* shipped with the **Web Components** technologies. All imported libraries will share the same namespace.
2. **Shadow DOM** is not about Javascript code isolation but only deals with DOM et CSS isolations.

If you want to resolve conflicts with imported 3rd-party libraries you could either:

- Design your website to import 3rd-party import only once, in a global dependency script.
- Use a module loader that will manage library loading for you, for example **require.js**, or the built-in feature ES6 module `import` feature, or even your own Vanilla module loader.
- Isolate the different parts of you site with `<iframe>`elements (if possible, but you may loose some interaction features).

All these solutations have advantages and drawbacks. It depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Supersharp. Modular approach has one important limitation, when you create new version of your one component you should update in main application, which automatically means build new version of main application, so the microservice will not be fully independent shippable.

Comment: I found interesting topic in Martin Fowler`s [blog](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html)